# Add a navigationbar with a back button to the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I need a step by step tutorial to add a navigation bar including a back button to my project.

My rootViewController defined in the `AppDelegate` is the LoginViewController. After successfull login it goes to the MainView and then to the SingleView

How would I add a navigation bar and a back button? This is the last thing I need for my app. I already tried many things

for example:

everything in the viewDidLoad method

First Try

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton          = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(refreshPropertyList:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = anotherButton;
```

Second Try

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(refreshPropertyList:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
```

What exactly do I write into the `RootViewController` and what do I write into the other `UIViewController` to get a butotn?

**Edit 2 after Popeye's suggestion**

```
//Appdelegate.m

LoginViewController *viewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [navCon setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    self.window.rootViewController      = viewController;

//LoginViewController.m
```

`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];`

```
ToDoListViewController  *viewController = [[ToDoListViewController alloc] init];
            viewController.stringUserId             = //userid//;
            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];

//ToDoListViewController.m

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

UIBarButtonItem *myBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
myBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";

UINavigationItem *right = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello!"];
right.leftBarButtonItem = myBarButtonItem;

[self.navigationController.navigationBar pushNavigationItem:right animated:YES];
```

still, no buttons!

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380 before asking a question

Comment: I googled, but that is the problem. None of that worked. I tried out the link you posted, but it doesn't work. That's why I'm stuck.

I have these methods

`- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(Back)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
}

- (IBAction)Back
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; // ios 6
}`

Comment: You need to share this information we're not mind readers we don't know what you have looked at so far. Please update your question

Comment: Step by Step tutorial : http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: I'm not using storyboards, but thanks!

Comment: @Popeye I updated my initial post

Comment: Why do you `alloc init` another `UINavigationController` in `LoginViewController` you can just call the initial one you created in your `AppDelegate` by calling `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];` and no need to create a new `UINavigationBar` in `MainViewController` as you can again call the initial one you created in `AppDelegate` by calling `self.navigationController.navigationBar`

Comment: Edit the initial post again. Still no buttons. :(

Answer (score 0):

Best way is add `NavigationController` to your **rootViewController** and you also able to hide and show NavigationBar by using following code

```
yourNavigationController.navigationBarHidden:YES/NO;
```

you can add rootViewController with navigationController by

```
LoginViewController *loginVC = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginVC];
navCon.navigationBarHidden = YES/NO;
self.window.rootViewController = navCon;
.
.
.
```